# Difference between MapBox and CartoDB

Tags: web-mapping, carto, mapbox

What is the difference between MapBox and CartoDB ?

Comment: I think there's some weird startup called ESRX or something too

Comment: MapBox, CartoDB and many other web mapping players are discussed at the Q&A that this appears to be a duplicate of.  In addition, one way to research the differences would be to review questions here tagged [tag:mapbox] and [tag:cartodb].

Comment: I think this moderation is a bit quick. There is only one message talking about CartoDB and Mapbox inside the (very interested) linked Q&A (actually two, with one giving a link to their respective pricing pages). Maybe I could edit my question to only focus on the comparison and not ask for the other players.

Comment: I think you are still asking for a list of differences between MapBox and CartoDB and by reading the duplicate Q&A I could find two or three without much trouble. To focus your question I think it needs to be more along the lines of "With respect to this key requirement ... how do MapBox and CartoDB compare?" or "I've tried meeting this requirement ... using MapBox/CartoDB without success, how does CartoDB/MapBox handle it?"

Comment: See here for one key difference between the two services
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88519/is-there-any-direct-access-to-mapbox-data-similar-to-cartodbs-sql-api/88627#88627